# Tandem nursing make my wife condition becoming worse

Tags: pregnancy

Since two months ago, my wife is pregnant and decide to keep breastfeeding our first son. This tandem nursing make my wife condition is becoming worse. My wife is having a flu for this two months. When my wife increase the frequency of breastfeeding, my wife's health is worser, the flu is getting heavy, plus a cough. This situation make us planning to stop tandem nursing. I am afraid that when the fetus is getting bigger, my wife body can't handle to do tandem nursing.
I did search and read articles related tandem nursing. But i haven't found that tandem nursing has probability to make mom conditions is getting worse, just like what happens to my wife. It seems that my wife body cannot handle to do tandem nursing.

Does anyone have ever face this situation? How do you handle this situation?
Any good references would be appreciated too.

Comment: Can you clarify what the difference between this question and [this one](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/my-wife-is-pregnant-again-does-she-need-to-stop-breastfeeding-our-son) might be?  You make reference to your wife's condition becoming worse.  What condition are you referring to?  Are you asking if breastfeeding while pregnant can complicate a medical condition?

Comment: Visit a doctor.

Comment: @Beofett, the other one question is related to breastfeeding when pregnant would harm the fetus. This one is about breastfeeding when pregnant would affect the mother's healthiness. And yes, I am asking whether breastfeeding while pregnant can complicate a medical condition.

Comment: @DaveClarke, I did, but her answers didn't fullfil my curiousness.

Comment: @kalingga As Dave Clarke said, you need to see a doctor. A flu shouldn't last 2 months, and breastfeeding shouldn't (to my knowledge) make her flu symptoms worse. I don't believe your question is answerable without falling into the realm of "specific medical advice".

Answer (score 2):

You don't explain what you mean by *"wife's condition is becoming worse"* but if your wife is having problems with breastfeeding while pregnant, I would suggest to **simply stop breastfeeding.** Since your first son is already more than one year old (you mentioned that [in this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/6226/my-wife-is-pregnant-again-does-she-need-to-stop-breastfeeding-our-son)), he does not *need* to be breastfed.

I assume that by *"tandem nursing"* you mean breastfeeding one child while being pregnant with another. At least, that's how I interpret your post.

Comment: To Torben : I edited my question. At first, I feel difficult how to describe my wife health condition. Yes, tandem nursing what I mean is breastfeeding while being pregnant.

Comment: About your answer, yes it is simply stop breastfeeding. and I am planning to do that. But I need others shares and opinions. Maybe one of the readers have faced same conditions like me. But they have another solutions without stopping breastfeeding their first son.